# How should one align nodes/shapes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

In my math class, I'm learning to write math papers.  It's actually an interesting class.  It's like an English class that makes sense.  In the paper we wrote on Polyhedra, I wrote a proof for why there exist only 5 Platonic Solids and then offered a graphical proof as well.  My graphical proof involved 3 hexagons to meet at a common vertex.  While writing the document, I tried in vain to find what I needed so I "brute forced" it and it was sufficient.  However, there must be a better way.  Please consider the below minimal, working, example and let me know the better way.  I'm going to have to push my limits of tikz for the final paper which will require a right triangle with equilateral triangles on the sides of the right triangle.  Some heavy tikz awaits.

Andy

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, calc, quotes, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum size=3cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6] (a) {};
\node[draw, minimum size=3cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6] (b) at (0,2.6cm) {};
\node[draw, minimum size=3cm,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6] (c) at (2.26cm,1.29cm) {};
\draw (a.corner 1) circle (1cm);
\draw (0,0) -- (a.corner 1) (0,0) -- (a.corner 6);
\draw (.33cm,0) arc (0:60:.33cm) node[right] {$60\degree$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which renders the following.  Which, though subtle, the hexagon to the right isn't perfectly aligned with the stacked two.

[image: Hexagons can't fold to 3-d]

Comment: I really wished it were possible to pick two answers.  Both respondents have nice solutions and should be recognised as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat more accurate.  The change to standalone is simply to save me the effort of cropping the image.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, calc, quotes, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
%\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={outer sep=-0pt}]
\node[draw, minimum size=3cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6] (a) {};
\node[draw, minimum size=3cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,anchor=corner 5] (b) at (a.corner 1) {};
\node[draw, minimum size=3cm,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,anchor=corner 3] (c) at (a.corner 1) {};
\draw (a.corner 1) circle (1cm);
\draw (0,0) -- (a.corner 1) (0,0) -- (a.corner 6);
\draw (.33cm,0) arc (0:60:.33cm) node[right] {$60\degree$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This answer is also quite intriguing.  Please explain how the `anchor` modifier works in relation to always making the two subsequent nodes at `a.corner 1`?

Comment: Normally nodes are placed so the center anchor is placed at the given location, but any anchor can be selected.  The only tricky part is finding the right corner.  Also, setting outer sep=0pt causes the borders to overlap rather than abut.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to place the hexagons relative to the centre of the circle, with that centre at `(0,0)`. Then we can use polar coordinates to place the hexagons and don't need to figure out how tall they are etc.

[If this is part of a larger diagram, you can use relative polar coordinates to place them around a point other than the origin.]

```
  \foreach \i [count=\j] in {0,120,240} \node (h\j) [my hexagon] at (\i:15mm) {};
```

I've used a loop, but we could equally use 3 `\node` commands if preferred. `my hexagon` is a style to make it easier to ensure consistent and flexible formatting.

```
\tikzset{%
    my hexagon/.style={draw, minimum size=3cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6},
}
```

Then the circle is also drawn at the origin.

```
  \draw circle (10mm);
```

We can then draw the lines of the angle and mark and label the angle.

I would use the `angles` library, since you are loading it. We name the coordinates `A`, `B` and `C` as the `angle` code will use these coordinates by default, so we may as well make it easy for ourselves. `angle radius` is the radius of the angle drawn in. `angle eccentricity` is the distance, relative to the `angle radius` of the label from `B`. That is, the label text will be at `2.1` times `2mm` i.e. `4.2mm` from `B`.

```
  \draw (h3.corner 6) coordinate (A) -- (h3.center) coordinate (B) -- (0,0) coordinate (C) pic ["$60\degree$", draw, angle eccentricity=2.1, font=\scriptsize, angle radius=2mm] {angle};
```

[I've adjusted the size to make the angle marking a bit smaller to avoid clashing with the circle, but obviously this can be adjusted as desired.]

Our hexagons then align quite nicely.

[image: better alignment]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
    my hexagon/.style={draw, minimum size=3cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i [count=\j] in {0,120,240} \node (h\j) [my hexagon] at (\i:15mm) {};
  \draw circle (10mm);
  \draw (h3.corner 6) coordinate (A) -- (h3.center) coordinate (B) -- (0,0) coordinate (C) pic ["$60\degree$", draw, angle eccentricity=2.1, font=\scriptsize, angle radius=2mm] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this answer and I appreciate the explanation.  May I ask, what is `\j` connected with in the loop?

Comment: @AndrewFalanga It is keeping a count of the iterations in the loop: 1, 2, 3 ....

Comment: Oh interesting.  So i iterates on the values provided while j it's a count of the iterations.  Is there anything special about j or could it be any name?

Comment: @AndrewFalanga It is just because I wrote `[count=\j]`. I could have written `\foreach \kangaroo [count=\banana] in ...` and used `\kangaroo` and `\banana` instead.